# Could we change the badge icons to an airplane outline?

Tags: feature-request

I was looking through the other SE sites and I saw that many of them have a badge icon that reflects part of their community (Curly brackets in the Code Review and Android icons in the Android one). Could we have a badge icon that have the shape of an airplane that would look like our community icon except the airplane is pointing straight up?

Comment: It's going to be a little while before we get a custom design that includes things like this (as mentioned in the [graduation post](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2844/1696)). Also, we have a related post about the [vote arrows](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/323/1696).